# How to extract list of dependencies from every microservice in java

Tags: spring-boot, maven, microservices, dependency-management

I am having a microservice architecture (Netflix in this case). I want to create an application that will get a list of dependencies for every microservice in that project. I want to do that in java because I need to provide those information's to another FE application. For example I have microservice A, B and C. I need to create an application that will expose endpoint from where you can see all dependencies for A, B and C.

I have tried using Aether but you need to tell the name of the artifact and it's not getting the right information (I think). 
I tried using: dependency:tree/list but I have no idea how to execute on every client. Even if I found a way I will have to get the data, parse it, convert it so finally it will be usable.

Comment: You would need to do something similar to the `BuildInfo` actuator. During compilation/building your project, generate a file containing all of your dependencies, wire that up to some actuator endpoint just like `BuildInfo`, then you can simply make a request to that endpoint.